# Повторно перевіряти (to double-check) - переперевіряти?

Tags: словотворення, милозвучність

Чи правильним є утворення дієслова (а від нього й іменника), за допомогою префікса *пере-*, що означає повторну дію (по аналогії з *переробити*, *переписати*, *перечитати* тощо), від дієслова **перевіряти** - **переперевіряти**?

Пошук у Goggle видає результати і з такою формою ([переперевірити](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruUA882UA882&oq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l2j69i60.5886j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)), і з близькою, але більше схожою на кальку з російської ([перепровірити](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&rlz=1C1SQJL_ruUA882UA882&sxsrf=ALeKk03e0odREmaIxNlxBKECmhrgY08Ngg:1582725247260&ei=f3hWXqvJD8yT8gLSvIKADg&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjrhI-Br-_nAhXMiVwKHVKeAOA4ChDy0wN6BAgLEDM&biw=1680&bih=907)).

Чи все ж варто як виняток та для уникнення нагромадження *пере* вживати ***повторно перевіряти***, ***додатково перевіряти*** тощо?

Answer (score 1):

#### Словники

> [Double](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double) - something that is twice the amount, size, strength, etc. of
>   something else.
>
> [To double-check](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-check): If you double-check something, you make certain it is
>   correct or safe, usually by examining it again.
>
> [ЗВІРЯ́ТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8) - Зіставляючи що-небудь із чимсь, перевіряти точність,
>   відповідність чому-небудь і т. ін.

#### Я теж маю слово

Значення double означає двічі, а отже в слові double-check мова йде не про повторність, а про подвійність. І у визначенні to double-check в кінці можна побачити again, тобто знову, а не про повторність. Подвійне звіряння. To **double-check** - **подвійно звірити**.